# C# WPF, window ellipses color update not happening until method is completely done running?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to make a stop light with the state pattern, so on my main window I have created three ellipses for each light color state. Within the main window I also have a button that will make a request to the light context.

```
 private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LightContext lc = new LightContext(new RedLight(),this);
        lc.Request();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        lc.Request();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        lc.Request();
    }
```

The way I have this set up is that after the context is created it makes the first request, which should set the light to the color red and gray out the two other lights, the system will then sleep for three seconds, make another request turning green, followed by yellow, then red again. The problem I am running into is that the colors do not change until the last request is made.. Which turns the light back to red so it looks like the light has never changed. If I comment out say the last request the light turns yellow once the two requests are done? How can I make the light change on each request then sleep so you can easily see the light change color.

```
public LightState LightState
    {
        get { return lightState; }
        set
        {
            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
            lightState = value;
            if (lightState.GetType().Name == nameof(RedLight))
            {
                mainWindow.RedLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
                mainWindow.YellowLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGray);
                mainWindow.GreenLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGray);
            }
            else if (lightState.GetType().Name == nameof(YellowLight))
            {
                mainWindow.YellowLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Yellow);
                mainWindow.GreenLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGray);
                mainWindow.RedLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGray);
            }
            else if (lightState.GetType().Name == nameof(GreenLight))
            {
                mainWindow.GreenLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);
                mainWindow.RedLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGray);
                mainWindow.YellowLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGray);
            }

        }
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` blocks the UI. Use an `async` Click handler and `await Task.Delay()` instead.

Comment: @Clemens Perhaps this should be an answer.